# Amazon Beanstalk Spring Boot deployment

Tags: spring, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying Spring Boot Application in Amazon BeanStalk.

Created a new RDS Postgres instance and connected to that instance using Postgres Client Application. Then created a new database in that. Then Changed database configuration to that instance in my local system Spring boot application. Then I able to connect to that database and use it through the application. But when deployed as a war file in Amazon Beanstalk. It is not working. Showing error as

Unable to obtain JDBC Connection

Any Solution?
Thanks in Adavance

Comment: Your EC2 and RDS in same VPC or diffeisrent VPC? Also check your Security group rules. Refer this below link for additional info:- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html

Comment: @MohanShanmugam Thanks